# images from array to img src of class in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have some code which tries to display temporary images from `tempimages[]` to `img` `src` with `id=slide` of `box002`, according to the random number selected from `arrayVariable` to `ptag[i]`.

I want to display `tempimages[0]` first on `img` `src` of class `box002`, after dropping that image it gets deleted by the function `Drop(ev)`, after that `tempimages[i]` should display `img` `src` of `box002` for dropping likewise.

How to display images from an image array `tempimages` to class box `img` `src`?

I have used the function `displayAllImages()` to allocate images to `img` `src` `id=slide`, but it failed to display images.

`box002` can be dragged and dropped to any box.

I want to display each image one by one from `tempimages[]` to `img` `src` of the box after each drop. How to change the code to achieve this property?

```js
var tempimages = [];
function rvalue() {
var array = [];
 var arrayVariable = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10']
  var ArrayOfImages = ['1.jpg', '2.jpg', '3.jpg', '4.jpg', '5.jpg', '6.jpg', '7.jpg', '8.jpg', '9.jpg', '10.jpg'];

  arrayLength = arrayVariable.length;
  ptags = document.getElementsByName("values");

  for (i = 0; i < ptags.length; i++) {
    ptags[i].innerHTML = arrayVariable[Math.floor(Math.random() * arrayLength)];
    array.push(ptags[i].textContent);
    tempimages.push(`${ptags[i].textContent}.jpg`); // want to display array to box002 to imgtag
 }
}

function displayAllImages() {
  var 
    i = 0,
    len = tempimages.length;    

  for (; i < tempimages.length; i++) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = tempimages[i];
    img.style.width = '100px';
    img.style.height = '100px';

    document.getElementById('slide').appendChild(img);
  }
};

$(function() {
  displayAllImages(); 
}); 

function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();

  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
  var el = document.getElementById(data);

  el.parentNode.removeChild; // deleting drag item
  ev.target.style.backgroundColor = 'initial'; //[value indicate which box element] bgcoclor none

  var pParagraph = ev.target.firstElementChild;
  ev.target.removeChild(pParagraph);
  alert(el);
}
```

```css
#container {
  margin-top:-2%;
  white-space:nowrap;
  text-align:center;
  margin-left:20%;
  margin-right:30%;
}

.box {
  background-color: coral;
  width: 60px;
  height:60px;
  margin-top:10px;
  display:inline-block;
  border-radius:5px;
  border:2px solid #333;
  border-color: #e6e600;
  border-radius: 10%;
  background-color:  #ffcc00;
}

.box002 {
  float: left;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  margin-left:30%;
  padding-top:2%;
  background-color:#ffff00 2px;
  border:2px solid #000066;
} 

.text {
  padding: 20px;
  margin:7 px;
  margin-top:10px;
  color:white;
  font-weight:bold;
  text-align:center;
}

#container {
  white-space:nowrap;
  text-align:center;
  margin-left:20%;
  margin-right:30%;
}

.text {
  padding: 20px;
  margin:7 px;
  margin-top:10px;
  color:white;
  font-weight:bold;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body onload="rvalue()">
  <div id="container">
    <div class="box"  ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="10">
      <p name="values"></p>
    </div>

    <div class="box"  ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="11">
      <p name="values"></p>
    </div>

    <div class="box"  ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="12">
      <p name="values"></p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="box002" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="2">
    <img src="" draggable="true" id="slide" style="width:30px; height:30px; border-radius: 50%;" border="rounded"/>    
  </div>    
</body>
```

Comment: Is this some sort of a group assignment? This is the 3rd time I've seen this code and each time it is a different SO user.

Comment: Is there any way to implement this. want to to display images stored in tempImages[] to img src in class box002...thanks in advance

Comment: I'm sure it can be done but the code formatting is such a mess that I am not inclined to read it and look for the problem.

Comment: can you please point out which portion of code need explanation. i can provide

Comment: Its needs some formatting, proper indentation. Somewhere in the middle there is a `<script>` tag which has no place there. What is that doing there? When you run the code you can't see the DOM elements because you log a bunch of information which winds up obscuring the UI. If you clean it up I'll look at it but in its current condition I rather answer someone else's question.

Comment: First of all the `'slide'` is `img` element and you try to `appendChild` to it which is not correct. You should rather change its `src` attribute or add other images with the same set of attributes under `<div id="2" ...>` element with `appendChild`.

Comment: I have corrected what Thijis has ponted out plaese check and reply

Comment: can anyone provide a code snippet so that i can undestand properly. thanks in advance

Comment: @devmaddy - you need to post only the *pertinent* code. Not everything. That's just laborious to read. Try to ascertain where your problem lies, and then provide just that part.

Comment: @thijs I have corrected what you have pointed out please check and reply

Comment: @utkanos want to display tempimages[0] first on img src of class box002, after dropping that image it gets deleted by the function Drop(ev), after that tempimages[i] should display img src of box002 for dropping likewise

Comment: The variable `tempimages` is declared inside `rvalue`, this method is its scope. When you want to use it in `displayAllImages` you can't read this variable as it is now out of scope. If you need `tempimages` to be available to both methods you need to declare it as global variable, outside either method.

Comment: @thijs i declared tempImages[] as global variable,  but still my problem exist,  display tempimages[0] first on img src of class box002, after dropping that image it gets deleted by the function Drop(ev), after that tempimages[i] should display img src of box002 for dropping likewise

Comment: @thijs image in tempImage array is not getting displayed in class box002 `img src`

Comment: @kamil-leis can you please provide a code snippet,  thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a 100% sure what it is you're trying achieve but here is something which might get you to the where you want to get. It picks three items at random and updates the image in the slide element after each time the slide is dropped on one of the boxes.

I've made a couple of changes, see the comments in the code as to why I've made the changes. When I saw this code first I didn't understand the need for two separate arrays so I've merged them into a single array.

```js
var tempimages = [];

function rvalue() {
  const
    items = [  
      { label: '1', url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=1' },
      { label: '2', url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=2' },
      { label: '3', url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=3' },
      { label: '4', url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=4' },
      { label: '5', url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=5' },
      { label: '6', url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=6' },
      { label: '7', url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=7' },
      { label: '8', url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=8' },
      { label: '9', url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=9' },
      { label: '10', url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=10' }
    ],
    ptags = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('[name="values"]'));
    
  ptags.forEach(ptag => {
    const
      // Generate a random index.
      randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length),
      // Get the at item from the random index (it is possible the same item
      // gets picked multiple times as there is no check for duplicates).
      item = items[randomIndex];
    // Update the label
    ptag.textContent = item.label;
    // Push the item into the array.
    tempimages.push(item);  
  });
}

function displayAllImages() {
  // Check if there are still images in the array, if not exit.
  if (tempimages.length === 0) {
    return;
  }
  
  const
    // Remove the item at index 0 from the array.
    item = tempimages.shift(),
    // Get the image element.
    image = document.getElementById('slide');
  // Update src attribute so it points to the new URL.
  image.src = item.url;
};

$(function() {
  // On start, do rvalue first. This is taken from the onload in the body
  // as that fired later than this method which meant displayAllImages was
  // called before rvalue.
  rvalue();
  displayAllImages(); 
}); 

function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();

  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
  var el = document.getElementById(data);

  el.parentNode.removeChild; // deleting drag item
  // ev.currentTarget is a div with class box whereas target can
  // be either the div or the p element. Using currentTarget ensures
  // you know which element you're working with.
  ev.currentTarget.style.backgroundColor = 'initial'; //[value indicate which box element] bgcoclor none

  var pParagraph = ev.currentTarget.firstElementChild;
  ev.currentTarget.removeChild(pParagraph);
  
  // Show the next image in the slider..
  displayAllImages();
}
```

```css
#container {
  margin-top:-2%;
  white-space:nowrap;
  text-align:center;
  margin-left:20%;
  margin-right:30%;
}

.box {
  background-color: coral;
  width: 60px;
  height:60px;
  margin-top:10px;
  display:inline-block;
  border-radius:5px;
  border:2px solid #333;
  border-color: #e6e600;
  border-radius: 10%;
  background-color:  #ffcc00;
}

.box002 {
  float: left;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  margin-left:30%;
  padding-top:2%;
  background-color:#ffff00 2px;
  border:2px solid #000066;
} 

.text {
  padding: 20px;
  margin:7 px;
  margin-top:10px;
  color:white;
  font-weight:bold;
  text-align:center;
}

#container {
  white-space:nowrap;
  text-align:center;
  margin-left:20%;
  margin-right:30%;
}

.text {
  padding: 20px;
  margin:7 px;
  margin-top:10px;
  color:white;
  font-weight:bold;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div class="box"  ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="10">
      <p name="values"></p>
    </div>

    <div class="box"  ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="11">
      <p name="values"></p>
    </div>

    <div class="box"  ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="12">
      <p name="values"></p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="box002" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="2">
    <img src="" draggable="true" id="slide" style="width:30px; height:30px; border-radius: 50%;" border="rounded"/>    
  </div>    
</body>
```

Comment: thisexplains a lot to me, thanks for this explanation wich help me an other